# Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm

Tags: android, ubuntu, github

I am trying to build Android from GitHub source code and I am getting the error:" build/core/envsetup.mk:94: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!.  Stop."

Any help is appreciated, I am trying to build using Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, upgrade to the newest version of Ubuntu(15.10 in my case) it was looking for a build version that was not supported in Ubuntu 14.04